# Find email addresses across multiple columns and copy them to one column

Tags: excel

I have an export from an old epos system that was used by computer illiterate individuals who put the email address in any field they chose. This means I have emails appearing in one of 4/5 columns. I would like to search all those columns and then copy any cell containing an @ symbol into a single column. Hopefully this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple INDEX/MATCH (with wildcards). Assuming your data is in A:E starting in Row2, in Row2 and copied down to suit:

```
=INDEX(A2:E2,MATCH("*@*",A2:E2,0))
```

Assumes only at most one email per row.

Comment: Thanks! will give it a try

Comment: You genius! it works beautifully.... I'm a php guy so excel is a black hole for me :D

Comment: Could you help me further? If I get an N/A can I delete the whole row?

Comment: Figured it out thanks. I used a find and replace function